# How to find the given premises are inconsistent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1) If Jack misses many classes through illness, then he fails high school.
2) If Jack fails high school, then he is uneducated.
3) If Jack reads a lot of books, then he is not uneducated.
4) Jack misses many classes through illness and reads a lot of books.

```
My trial is

P: Jack misses classes through illness
Q: He fails high school
R: He is uneducated
S: Jack reads a lot of Books

Premise 1 : P -> Q
Premise 2 : Q -> R
Premise 3 : S -> not(R)
Premise 4 : P ^ S

Now, ( P -> Q)^(Q -> R)^(S -> not(R))^(P^S) ==> P^not(P)

  {1}       (1) P ^ S      (Rule P)
  {1}       (2) P          (Rule T,Simplification Rule )
  {3}       (3) P -> Q     (Rule P )
  {1,3}     (4) Q          (Rule T,Modus Ponens Rule)
  {5}       (5) Q -> R     (Rule  P)
  {1,3,5}   (6) R          (Rule T,Modus Ponens Rule)
  {7}       (7) S -> R     (Rule P)
  {1,3,5,7} (8) not(S) V R (Rule T,Modus Tollens Rule)
```

I have tried like above .But I am not even getting the conclusion that it is inconsistency. Can anyone solve this for me .Please

Comment: P.3 is equivalent to : $R \to \lnot S$.

Comment: So from P1-3 we have $P \to \lnot S$ and $P \land S$ is equiv to $\lnot (P \to \lnot S)$.

Comment: Please see here: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=wwXItgjXaT0C&pg=PA73&dq=1)+If+Jack+misses+many+classes&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi517L3w-zQAhUEqo8KHYThCPkQ6AEIGTAA#v=onepage&q=1)%20If%20Jack%20misses%20many%20classes&f=false

Comment: Thank You @Rohan .. It helped me.

Comment: Thank You @MauroALLEGRANZA for your answer.